# Django template tag, making my list empty or I'm not pass anything

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates

Thanks for reading my post

okay, I'm currently working on Django project that displays data in a dashboard; I manage to display and draw charts with Chart JS, great but now I need to limited number data in Django database to be displayed on charts and display the most recent data put into the database.

I use Django built-in tag to display the most recently is "last" and limiting the display data, the tag is "length_is"(**Solve**).

Here are my HTML codes for using the "last" tag and index page

```
<div class = "containor">
    <div class = "float-right  my-4 chartjs-render-monitor" id="chartContainerPH" style="width: 49%; height: 400px;display: inline-block; background-color:#FDFDFD;">
    <center>
        <a class="title-link" href="{%url 'ph' %}">PH:</a>
        <p>{% for tank_system in tank %} {{tank_system.ph|last}} {%endfor%}</p>
        </center>
    {%include 'FrounterWeb/includes/PHchart.html'%}
    </div>
```

This is the result I get [Last Tag result in my index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAOCS.png)

---

(**Solve**)
Here' my code for chart HTML which I use the length_is tag

```
{%block PHchart%}

<canvas class = "my-4 chartjs-render-monitor" id="PHchart" ></canvas>
<script>

var ctx = document.getElementById("PHchart");
var PHchart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: [ {%for tank_system in tank%} "{{tank_system.datetime}}", {%endfor%} ], //x-Axis
        datasets: [{ //y-Axis
        label: 'PH1',
            data: [ {%for tank_system in tank%} {{tank_system.PH|length_is:"3"}}, {%endfor%} ],
            backgroundColor: "rgb(249, 24, 24,0.2)",
            borderColor: "rgb(249, 24, 24,0.2)",
            fill: true,
            }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:false
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
</div>{%endblock%}
```

and the result [Length_is on chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Hq4r.png)

---

Summary: I can't get the built-in "filter" and "length_is"(**Solve**) Django tags to work.  Could you please share an example or tutorial with me?  The Django documentation didn't write many examples.

and here my views codes;

```
    @login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def index(request):
    tank = tank_system.objects.all()
    args = {'tank':tank}
    return render(request,'FrounterWeb/extends/includes.html',args)
```

and my models' codes;

```
class tank_system(models.Model):
    PH = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
    EC = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
    WaterLevel = models.IntegerField(default=100)
    TempWater = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    TempRoom = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these filters are well documented in the django docs.  The [`last` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#last) gets you the last element of a `list`, and the [`length_is` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#length-is) returns `True` if the list is that length, or `False` otherwise.

This likely means that there is an issue in your understanding of your code.  You'll want to verify the type and the values of `tank_system.PH` or `tank_system.ph` (you have both) and the case will matter.  One way to debug this is to simply output the value of `tank_system.ph` to the web page and verify the result.

Comment: Okay I get on the length_is, is not used properly; but how do I use to sort what I want to show, in my list, example I had a list [1,2,3,4,5,6] and I only want to show 3, 5 and 6

Comment: As for "last" tag is use properly, if I was to put in; {% for tank_system in tank %} {{tank_system.EC|last}}, {%endfor%}(which create a list) I had typeErrors, then how do i solve this issue?

Comment: I can't really help you solve wither of these unless you post additional information regarding the data and format of `tank`.  We're shooting in the dark without that.

Comment: For the 3, 5, 6 question, you'd have to [write your own filter](http://www.pfinn.net/custom-django-filter-tutorial.html).

Comment: So `tank_system.EC` isn't a list or another `Iterable`.  It is a `Decimal`.  Do you want the last number in the `Decimal`?  Like for `3.7` you want the `7`?

Comment: 3.7 I said, in other I wish to grab the last element on the list and display it